# What does the "user" object refer to in the "Auth" feature of Plaid?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, plaid

Im using Plaid [Plaid.com](https://plaid.com/)

Im using Plaid's Auth feature to verify account details. I found in the docs that it needs a "user" object while creating an item (asking the legalName and email of the user). 
Here is what the doc says:

> **user** (optional)   *Specify a user object to enable all Auth features.* 
>   Required fields are: **legalName** – your user's legal first and last name
>   **emailAddress** – your user's associated email address

Im confused that which user are they asking for? Is it my Plaid account's user. Or the real user in my application (customer) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user object is only necessary if you want to use the additional Auth features such as microdeposits - this would be for the end user (so in your case, the real user in your application/the customer).

Comment: Yes. That helped me.